# Parsing XML Data in Android

Tags: android, xml, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I know this type of question has been asked before but I cannot find an answer for my issue. And the answers to my previous question unfortunately don't work
I have an xml file which stores LatLng values and an icon name for markers which I want to be displayed on a map. The map works, but I cannot seem to get the code for the xml to work

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>
<marker>
<lat>51.500906</lat>
<lng>-0.124433</lng>
<icon>landmark</icon>
</marker>
</markers>
```

And this is my code that I am using (should I be creating a new class file or adding a class to my MainActivity class)?

```
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);

DocumentBuilderFactory dfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(in, null);

NodeList markers = doc.getElementsByTagName("marker");

for (int i = 0; i < markers.getLength(); i++){
Element item = (Element) markers.item(i);
String stringLat = item.getAttribute("lat");
String stingLng = item.getAttribute("lng");
String icon = item.getAttribute("icon");
Double lat = Double.valueOf(stringLat);
Double lng = Double.valueOf(stringlng);
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();

map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions)
.position(new LatLng(lat, lng)) 

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

In the above code I get errors for the Document doc line and the .getAttribute lines as well as the .position line, all other lines do not bring up errors in Eclipse

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: I don't get any errors from this code other than a general warning that the DocumentBuilder stuff needs to be wrapped in a try/catch. I didn't try the map api parts but the lines you refer to work fine for me.

Comment: Hi Robert. When I type Document doc = db.parse(in, null) Eclipse gives me an error asking if I want to create a class called Document. Also should the java code be in a public void method or a public class? Thanks

Comment: Where you place this code doesn't really matter.  It's a design question more than a technical question.  It will work fine anywhere, really.   It sounds like you are missing an import for the Document class?  Is there an "import org.w3c.dom.Document;" in your imports at the top of the code?

Comment: Oooops :/ *sigh*, I have imported the DocumentBuilderFactory and the DocumentBuilder but haven't imported the Document namespace, Thank you. I will try that when I get home. Thank you. Not sure I can tick your answer on here as a comment can I?

Comment: There, now you can. No problem, glad I could help.  We've all done it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing an import for the Document class? Is there an "import org.w3c.dom.Document;" in your imports at the top of the code?

Comment: Hi Robert. I have imported the org.w3c.dom.Document in my class, but I go to code it, I don't get the .getAttribute option on the lines of String stringLat = item. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My Code::: public void showmypoi() {
   InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.coords);
   
   DocumentBuilderFactory dfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = dfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = db.parse(in, null);
   
   NodeList markers = doc.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   
   for (int i = 0; i < markers.getLength(); i++){
    Element item = (Element) markers.item(i);
    String stringlat = item.???
    Double lat = Double.valueOf(stringLat);
    Double lng = Double.valueOf(stringLng);

Comment: Hmmm, well, those are Elements.  Did you also add the org.w3c.dom.Element import?